# Group all the same values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query that I want to use for 2 different purposes instead of adding the query two times.

The array contains materials belonging to categories.

I get them using the following query:

```
SELECT cnt.title as content_title,
cnt.alias as content_alias,
cnt.id as content_id,
cnt.catid, 
cnt.introtext,
cnt.images,
cat.id as cat_id,
cat.parent_id, 
cat.title as cat_title,
cat.alias as cat_alias
FROM snm_content cnt
INNER JOIN snm_categories cat
ON cnt.catid = cat.id
WHERE cat.parent_id = 15
```

First I have a dropdown with all the categories, and beneath it all the materials (so a user can filter them later on when I add that). However with this query it gets all products and their category names, so in the dropdown all categories are shown multiple times instead of just one time.

I know I can group them in my query, but that would mean I would have to add a second query to show all the products beneath the dropdown.

So my question:
How can I group all categories in my array?

There must be a simple php function for this.

Comment: Please add a desired output because ''group all categories in my array'' doesn't mean anything

Comment: @DanielE.I thought that would be clear from my post. I get all materials and their categories using that query, so material 1 (category 1), material 2 (category 1), using that same query I want to show all categories in a dropdown, but only each category one time, not for every material.

Comment: the php function `array_unique`?

Comment: @GertKommer Thats exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can group them.

For example

```
$pets = array('type' => 'dog', 'age' => 1, 'type'=>'cat', 'age' => 2);
```

You can use `array_column` to group each column such that:

```
var_dump(array_column($pets, 'type'));
```

Produce:

```
array('dog', 'cat');
```